# Wie kann der Genitiv in dieser Nominalgruppe vermieden werden?

Tags: grammaticality, genitive, style, technical-terminology

Ich habe diese Nominalgruppe ins Deutsche übersetzt:

> die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und **der Hintergrund der Icons**

Aber ich finde den Genitiv des Genitivs unpraktisch zu lesen, zudem sieht es irgendwie falsch aus.

---

> die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und **der Icon-Hintergrund**

Kann diese Nominalgruppe anstelle der letzten verwendet werden? Oder habt ihr andere oder bessere Vorschläge?

---

#### EDIT (verbesserte Version)

> die Hintergrundfarben der Anwendung und der Icons

Es handelt sich letztendlich um die Hintergrundfarbe der beiden Nomen.
Kann diese Nominalgruppe wie folgt gekürzt werden, da sie einfacher ist?

> die Hintergrundfarben der Anwendung und Icons

Comment: Ich würde schreiben: ... die Hintergrundfarben der Anwendung und der Icons.

Comment: Ich würde Deinen Edit (zumindest den ersten Teil) eher als Antwort auf Deine Frage schreiben (was erlaubt und gewünscht ist), ggf. mit Verweis auf den inspirierenden Kommentar.

Comment: Ich stimme @HaraldLichtenstein mit seinem Vorschlag zu. Darüber hinaus möchte ich anmerken, dass die Wenung *der Hintergrund der Icons* keinen doppelten Genitiv enthält, sondern einen Nominativ mit Genitivattribut. Daher bedeutet die gesamte erste Wendung auch nicht das, was Sie offenbar aussagen wollen, auch wenn sie grammatikalisch einwandfrei ist.

Comment: Iconhintergrund wäre die korrekte Schreibweise, für die Zusammensetzung.

Comment: Ich stimme @HaraldLichtenstein zu, es wird "die Hintergrundfarben" (plural) lauten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich würde es ohne Genitiv formulieren:

> die Hintergrundfarbe von Anwendung und Icons

So lässt sich ein Nebeneinander verschiedener Arten von *der* und *der* vermeiden:

- In «die Hintergrundfarben der Anwendung und der Icons» ist das erste *der* ein Genitiv feminin und das zweite Genitiv plural.
- In «die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und der Hintergrund der Icons» kommt noch das mittlere *der* im Nominativ maskulin hinzu.

---

Die Formulierung «die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und Icons» ist ungrammatisch. Eine solche Zusammenziehung ist nur dann möglich, wenn zweimal derselbe Artikel vorliegt:

- die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendungen und Icons ← die Hintergundfarbe der Anwendungen und der Icons (zweimal Genitiv plural)
- die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und Bebilderung ← die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und der Bebilderung (zweimal Genitiv feminin)
- die Hintergrundfarbe des Programms und Icons ← die Hintergrundfarbe des Programms und des Icons (zweimal Genitiv maskulin)

Nicht möglich sind hingegen Zusammenziehungen bei zwei verschiedenen Artikeln, und zwar nicht einmal dann, wenn diese dieselbe Form haben:

- *Ungrammatisch:* die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und Icons

  - ← die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und der Icons (Genitiv plural vs. Genitiv feminin)
  - ← die Hintergrundfarbe der Anwendung und des Icons (Genitiv plural vs. Genitiv maskulin)
- *Ungrammatisch:* die Hintergrundfarbe des Programms und Bebilderung ← die Hintergrundfarbe des Programms und der Bebilderung (Genitiv maskulin vs. Genitiv plural)